# Why does Ash look more like the male character from the respective Pokémon games?

Tags: character, pokemon

In the Pokémon XY series Ash was dressed up and looking a bit like Calem, the male player character from XY games.

In the sun moon series he is dressed up and looks like sun from the Pokémon sun moon games.

I am not sure about the other regions but I know in kanto and orange islands he doesn't...

Why is he dressed up like that?

Answer (score 0):

The anime is used to promote the games and merchandising opportunities. This is just another step towards that goal.